# How to show same company's different office address in google based on the user's country?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, local-seo, google-business

our company has five offices in five countries , once the user search in google, I need to show the office address based on the user's country, for example if the user search from US , I need google to show US office address automatically, also if the user search a specific office address then the search result will show that country office address, for example, the user search "ABC UK or ABC UK office address " then the search result shows the UK office address. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you already created local business listings for each of your offices with Google?